# Do distros use different wifi drivers?

Tags: wifi, hardware, hardware-compatibility

I have two laptops, the old one running manjaro, but I use the new one and it's running windows 10, I want to run some Linux distro on it but [I can't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822898/broadcom-bcm43142-issues), my wireless card gives me many problems that I had no choice but reinstalling windows 10.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

My question: Is there a chance that different distros have different drivers? For instance Manjaro supported my wireless driver on the old laptop while linux mint didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have installed `yaourt` and `base-devel` ,to get the wifi working under Manjaro , you need to install the [`broadcom-wl-dkms`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl-dkms/) package from AUR:

```
yaourt -S  broadcom-wl-dkms
```

Then unload conflicting drivers :

```
rmmod b43
rmmod ssb
rmmod bcma
```

Reload the right driver:

```
modprobe -r wl
modprobe wl
```